# Cannot install en_core_web_sm with Connection error

Tags: installation, spacy

I strictly followed the instruction on https://spacy.io/usage:

```sh
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy[cuda101]
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

There was no problem with first two lines, but when I tried with line3, I got the error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8f0c68bf40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I'm using Linux and python3.8.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to install the SpaCy pipelines, which is to directly download from GitHub repo https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_lg-3.0.0 and use `pip install`.

However, I still what to know how can it be wrong to follow official instructions?

Comment: Hey, we've had people report issues like that before and it's always something weird with their Internet connections. Are you on a corporate network or some other kind of network that filters traffic? Alternately, Github has been having some connection issues today.

Comment: @polm23 I believe there's something wrong with my Internet connection, but  I successfully installed the same pipeline under the same network several days before. Maybe my connection is just not stable enough.